# What are the EU-equivalent terms of the FAA ATC tower, TRACON, and center in radio calls?

Tags: air-traffic-control

Does ATC in the EU have equivalents to the US FAA tower, TRACON, and center facilities? What are they called?

Comment: This is too broad @jeff0000.

Comment: [Related](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/19365/62), but as you can see from that question (and others linked to it) this is probably a very broad question. If you're asking about the specific equivalents of Tower, Approach and Center then you might re-word your question to focus on that.

Answer (score 2):

Area control centre   CONTROL

Approach control    APPROACH

Approach control radar arrivals ARRIVAL

Approach control radar departures   DEPARTURE

Aerodrome control   TOWER

Surface movement control     GROUND

Radar (in general)  RADAR

Precision approach radar   PRECISION

Direction- finding station HOMER

Flight information service INFORMATION

Clearance delivery DELIVERY

Apron service APRON

Company dispatch DISPATCH

Aeronautical station RADIO

Aerodrome Flight Information Service AFIS

Heliport Information Service HIS