# What is the relationship between the EASA and JAA?

Tags: easa, eu

I have heard of two different European aviation authorities: EASA and JAA (or JAAT).

What is the difference in their functions?  This would include things such as:

1. Whether they are somehow part of the same organization, but are referred
   to separately (such as the FAA and NTSB both being US government agencies).
2. One being the parent organization of the other.
3. Whether they are separated by which countries they oversee within Europe.
4. Whether they issue separate licenses/certificates.
5. Whether one is an older version of the other similar to the CAA being the predecessor to the FAA.

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/1210/19

Comment: This question seems much more detailed & specific than the suggested duplicates. Voting to leave open.

Comment: @DeltaLima Yes, mostly.  It is semantically accurate to say one is the predecessor to the other or not really?

Comment: Yes, I guess one can say that, especially for the EU member states. Note that each EU member state still has a CAA, which has the responsibility to, amongst others, issue and revoke flight crew licenses. But they follow the EU and EASA directives and guidelines to do so. So when we talk about an EASA Pilot License, it typically is a license that is issued by the CAA of one of the EU Member states, in accordance with EU regulations.